# Create docker container from within a container

Tags: docker

I have docker on my host machine with a container running. I was wondering if it's possible, and what the best approach would be, to "trigger" a container creation from the running container.

Let's say my machine is **host** and I have a container called **app** (with id **123456789**) running on host.

```
root@host $ docker contain ls
123456789    app_mage    ....    app
```

I would like to create a container on **host** from within **app**

```
root@123456789 $ docker run --name app2 ...
```

```
root@host docker container ls
123456789    app_mage    ....    app
12345678A    app_mage    ....    app2
```

What I need is for my **app** to be running on docker and to run arbitrary applications in an isolated environment (but I'd rather avoid docker-in-docker)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting and stopping docker container from other container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961073/starting-and-stopping-docker-container-from-other-container)

Comment: The best approach is to architect your application to not need this.  If you must, you can mount the host's Docker socket into the container, but it will have unrestricted root-level access over the host.

Comment: Do you know if other tools (like docker engine, docker machine) could be helpful here?

Comment: @DavidMaze could you provide an answer here on how to architect a system that avoids this situation? Supposing that one service is a sort of api that orchestrates the need for ephemeral services that could run on docker

Comment: A pattern I tend to recommend here is some sort of job-queueing system.  You can have a long-running worker that handles jobs.  This setup won't be intrinsically tied to any specific container technology, though: you could run the worker locally without a container, or multiple replicas of it in Kubernetes, without requiring privileged access and without changing code.

Answer (score 5):

A majority of the Docker community will veer away from these types of designs, however it is very doable.

Similar to [Starting and stopping docker container from other container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40961073/starting-and-stopping-docker-container-from-other-container) you can simply mount the docker.sock file from the host machine into the container, giving it privilege to access the docker daemon.

To make things more automated, you could use the [docker-py sdk](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#) to start containers from inside a container, which would in turn access the Docker deamon on the host machine hosting the container that you are spawning more containers from.

For example:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock image1 --name test1

----

import docker
def create_container():
    docker.from_env().containers.run("image2", name="test2")
```

This example starts container test1, and runs that method inside the newly created container, which in turn creates a new container test2 running on the same host as test1.